# where is the code for conditional get like ${ client?.name } in the playframework?

Tags: playframework

I need to get elements if not null when using JsonElement.

this doesn't work when using JsonElement
${ client?.name }

Does anybody knows how Play! does this evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional `?.` notation is part of Groovy and not Java. Therefore this notation is only available in the Groovy templating engine. It sounds like you are trying to use the same notation in your Java classes, which cannot be done.

You can read more about the Groovy "Safe Navigation Operator" at the groovy site - http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator

Answer (score 1):

Play use groovy to evaluate java expression in groovy templates. It based on Java bean spec. Say you have an object `client`, with a public method `getName()`, then you can do `${client.name}` or `${client.getName()}`, in addition, play groovy template engine can safe your typing by allowing you to use `${client?.name}`. Back to your case, if client is a JsonElement, then you might be able to get the name property by `${client?.getAsJsonObject()?.get("name")}`

Comment: SO, it's not possible to add a JavaExtension or something similar to avoid NullPointerException ?
I'd like to have a cleaner code

Comment: It's not about NPE, the expression `${client?.getAsJsonObject()?.get("name")}` is safe from NPE already. The problem is you cannot use `${client.name}` and expect it automatically become ${client.getAsJsonObject().get('name')}`